# How can I create multiple performance test result reports on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a small problem about **JMeter** integration with Jenkins and I hope you can solve it. Let me explain it;

I have 3 different jmx (JMeter) files. I can run it via Windows bash command and I successfully create jtl log file for Performance plugin on Jenkins. Windows bash command is this for one of them;

```
cd C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\ && jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\load_tests\testrun.jmx -l C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\load_tests\logs\testrun.jtl
```

However, Performance plugin allows only one performance test result. I want separate graphics and reports for each test file. When add `"Publish performance test result report"` and type `"C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\load_tests\logs\*.jtl"`, it combines all result. As I said I need separate test result reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. My Jenkins version is not compatible with JMeter 4.0 that's why I use JMeter 3.3 and it works perfectly. Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I havent used it much with Jenkins.

But, if it allows for 1 then you can create 3 jenkin plans and execute them and all will get their individual report. Until, you have some specific dependencies between the 3 jmx plans.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins performance plugin states

If you just have one report file, the graph of this reports will appear on the main page.

If you have more than one report file, you have to click on “Performance Trend” and the graphs will appear.

So more than one report file is possible.